# C Programming times and clock functions

Tags: c, unix, time

I'm working on a Linux 4.4 kernel (Ubuntu) and comparing the output between the `times` function (in sys/times.h) and the `clock` function (in time.h).

According to the man pages, `times` should return the "CPU time" used by the program starting from some arbitrary time (but that arbitrary time should be consistent between invocations of the function).

Also according to the man pages, `clock` should return an approximation of the processor time used by the program.

The code below uses each of these calls to print the amount of time it takes to do some arbitrary work. It seems like these times should line up, but they always seem to be off by a factor of 10,000.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    struct tms times_start, times_end;
    clock_t times_start_retval, times_end_retval;
    clock_t clock_start, clock_end;

    /* clock called first and last, so estimates using "clock" should be
       slightly longer than estimates using "times" */
    if((clock_start = clock()) == -1) {
        perror("starting clock");
        return -1;
    }

    if((times_start_retval = times(&times_start)) == -1) {
        perror("starting times");
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i = 100000000; i; i--); // do work

    if((times_end_retval = times(&times_end)) == -1) {
        perror("ending timer");
        return -1;
    }

    if((clock_end = clock()) == -1) {
        perror("ending clock");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Times using the clock system call\n");
    printf("clock start: %li\nclock end: %li\n", clock_start, clock_end);
    printf("elapsed: %li\n\n", clock_end - clock_start);

    printf("Times using the times system call\n");
    printf("System start: %li\nUser start: %li, start retval: %li\n",
        times_start.tms_stime, times_start.tms_utime, times_start_retval);
    printf("System end:   %li\nUser end:   %li, end retval:   %li\n",
        times_end.tms_stime, times_end.tms_utime, times_end_retval);
    printf("elapsed: %li\n\n", times_end_retval - times_start_retval);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
Times using the clock system call
clock start: 5016
clock end: 321323
elapsed: 316307

Times using the times system call
System start: 0
User start: 0, start retval: 1733759140
System end:   0
User end:   31, end retval:   1733759172
elapsed: 32
```

Based on the descriptions, it seems like these should return the same time. The fact that they are not has me wondering about potential portability issues. Why are these times different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I just needed to ask the question. I think I just found the answer in *The Linux Programming Interface* (Kerrisk 2011, pg 206-207). The answer appears to be the the “CPU time” is measured in two different ways.

times returns time measured in “clock ticks.” The number of clock ticks per second can be retrieved using `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` and for my system is 100. So each clock tick is about 1/100 of a second.

clock returns time measured in “clocks per second.” Apparently for Unix-compliant systems this should always be 1,000,000. when I print CLOCKS_PER_SEC from the time.h header file, that is what I get on my system.

To get the number of seconds, I must divide the `clock` return value by 1,000,000, or divide the `times` return value by 100. This means that for every “clock tick” there are 10,000 “clocks.” That seems to explain the factor of 10,000 difference I saw.

Comment: The information is also available in the man pages. One just has to read the carefully.